# Publishing a different apk in the play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have already published an app for the google play store, and now it is in use by around 1000 users and is still growing. However, I find that the code which I used is quite cluttered for me to add new features, and so I am planning to write a different version of the app. I have two questions:-

1. Is it possible to publish an app with a different package name under the same listing I have used for the original, and how should I do this?
2. If I cannot do the above, can I publish a different app with the same package name for this to work?

This whole scenario is given that I have all the signing credentials for the old and new apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO it is not possible to publish an app with a different package name but you can change the version code and republish this app with new code by signing the app with the same credential. hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can only update with same package name. with same keystore and password